# LG Watch Style USB Debugging - computer not recognizing presence of watch

Tags: adb, usb-debugging, lg, android-wear

I am trying to develop for my LG Watch Style and I am having trouble getting my computer to recognize its plugged in. I've tried reinstalling the Google USB drivers and resetting the watch.

It's almost like the charger that came with the watch is not capable of sending data.

Does anybody know any debugging secrets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the LG Watch Style's charger has NO DATA PIN.

The workaround for me was to use [Bluetooth debugging](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/debugging.html), you will need an Android phone with a USB cable and a computer running the ADB server. Wifi debugging is also an option but that requires a USB connection initially (maybe it can be bootstrapped through bluetooth?)

Comment: Can't believe LG actually did that...